# Add space in Array Items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with key value pair items I want to add space in Every Key after every capital letter.

```
var items = [
    {
        "BrandConstruct": 165,
        "YearPlanData": "a"
    },
    {
        "BrandConstruct": 236,
        "YearPlanData": "c"
    },
    {
        "BrandConstruct": 376,
        "YearPlanData": "b"
    }

]
```

Above is my array and I want it as below:-

```
 var items = [
    {
        "Brand Construct": 165,
        "Year Plan Data": "a"
    },
    {
        "Brand Construct": 236,
        "Year Plan Data": "c"
    },
    {
        "Brand Construct": 376,
        "Year Plan Data": "b"
    }

]
```

and again I want to do it back in original form in javascript

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong with your attempt? There's plenty of resources on similar issues from which you can get and apply solutions to yours. You only said what you want and SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Actually I am Using Handsontable plugin so I Use  BrandConstruct, YearPlanData as My table headers. So i want to show them with space and when Save it again set to orignal form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var result = items.map(o => {                          //Loop thru the array using map
  return Object.entries(o).reduce((c, [k, v]) => {     //Convert the object into an array using Object.entries | Use reduce to group the array
    return Object.assign(c, {                          //Use Object.assign to create new object
      [k.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")]: v              //Use regex to split the key by capital letter and join
    })
  }, {});
});
```

Here is a snippet (shorter version):

```js
var items = [{"BrandConstruct":165,"YearPlanData":"a"},{"BrandConstruct":236,"YearPlanData":"c"},{"BrandConstruct":376,"YearPlanData":"b"}]
var result = items.map(o => Object.entries(o).reduce((c, [k, v]) => Object.assign(c, {[k.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")]: v}), {}));

console.log(result);
```

You can use `Object.keys()` for Angular and IE9 compatible:

```js
var items = [{"BrandConstruct":165,"YearPlanData":"a"},{"BrandConstruct":236,"YearPlanData":"c"},{"BrandConstruct":376,"YearPlanData":"b"}];

var result = items.map(function(o) {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce(function(c, k) {
    c[k.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")] = o[k];
    return c;
  }, {})
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where to use above code on client side or server side?

Comment: It's Javascript (as your question is tagged with), so client side. Unless you're using Node.js, but you've made no mention of that

Comment: I am using javascript. but this code  shows error in javascript at [k, v]

Comment: @Anshul What is the error? Where do use this? frontend?

Comment: I am using angular js1 simply

Comment: You can use `Object.keys` for angular. I added a new block of code @Anshul

Comment: Thank You so much. Its is working Could you please tell me How to undo again it in orignal form?

Comment: This will be saved on a new variable, no need to undo. Your `item` variable will still be unchanged.

Comment: Yes I know But when I perform edit operation then I need to send array with changed values in Orignal form

Comment: Ohh okay just replace  `[k.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")]: o[k]` to `[k.split(" ").join("")]: o[k]`

Comment: This code is not working with internet explorer please suggest another way for it

Comment: @Anshul IE is not compatible with arrow function and Object.assign. I updated the code.

Comment: Object.keys also not compatible for IE @Eddie

Comment: Hmm i tested this code on ie11 and as per the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: It is compatible as per the do

Comment: Maybe it is a different code that is making the error? I tested just this code on ie11 and works just fine

Comment: Is there anu another way to do same?  or server side in c# when I bind the list can i do it there? @Eddie